# Seating-Chart Optimization

Tags: optimization

Does anyone have any ideas on a seating chart optimization formula for a call center environment? There are "docks" in which the workers sit. Each dock has approximately 15 seats, some more some less. The workers are on teams and work the same schedule and sit in their dock together. The problem is there are more teams than there are docks. Some work day shift, some work mid shift, and some work night shift. The formula would need to identify where the "optimal" bay would be for each team based off of number of workers, days worked, shift start time, and shift end time. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "formula"? You seem to be looking for a scheduling algorithm. I believe that this is a rather wide area, known sometimes as [planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_planning_and_scheduling).

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as too broad. The question isn't just "Scheduling -- tell me all about that" but, rather, "How can I schedule this particular system." The asker doesn't know enough about scheduling to ask a more precise question, but that's exactly why they're asking at all.

Comment: Yes, I am not very familiar with scheduling / planning. Do you have any info on where info on how to do something like this could be located? Can this be done in a program like Excel?

Comment: I'd suggest you read Yuval's link and read about integer linear programming and perhaps operations research, then use that to edit your question to tell us about (a) what approaches you've considered and why you rejected them, and (b) give a precise specification of exactly what your requirements/objective function is.  I don't think there's enough detail in the question as it stands to recommend a particular approach or solution or algorithm.